# Error Installing Installing JDK jdk-9.0.1-oth-JPR in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

To fix the following issue do the following

Manage Jenkins » Global Tool Configuration

- Remove the auto-installer for the JDK that downloads it from the Oracle site.

Building remotely on in workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\

```
Installing JDK jdk-9.0.1-oth-JPR
FATAL: Unable to produce a script file
hudson.AbortException: Couldn't find the right download for WINDOWS and i386 combination
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.locate(JDKInstaller.java:443)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:138)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:72)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:144)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:358)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2264)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:921)
    at com.lookout.jenkins.EnvironmentScript.generateEnvironment(EnvironmentScript.java:147)
    at com.lookout.jenkins.EnvironmentScript.setUp(EnvironmentScript.java:119)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage Jenkins » Global Tool Configuration

Remove the auto-installer for the JDK that downloads it from the Oracle site.

Answer (score 0):

Step:1 Go to Mangae Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration

Step:2 Go to JDK Section -> JDK installations

Step:3 Remove Install automatically

Step:4 Add "JAVA_HOME" path manually that is your system java home path